# C++ array of strings error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string [200]' to 'std::string &'

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm very new at C++ programming, I'm just practicing. And this is my first topic here on stackoverflow (since now I've ever used this on google searchs...)

I'm trying to make a function return a full vector of strings.
Of course I can't use a default return, so I've made a void function with a pointer as parameter and it'll copy the vector to the parameter

what I tried to do:

```
class CadastroPessoas
{
private:
    string dadosPessoais[MAX_PESSOAS];
public:
    void lerDadosTodasPessoas(string &vetor);
    /*
        outras coisas...
    */
};

void CadastroPessoas::lerDadosTodasPessoas(string &vetor)
{
    vetor = this->dadosPessoais;
}
```

but when I do something like:

```
CadastroPessoas * EmpresaPessoas = new CadastroPessoas()
string dadosPessoais[MAX_PESSOAS];
EmpresaPessoas->lerDadosTodasPessoas(dadosPessoais);
```

and I get this error message:
`cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string *[200]' to 'std::string &'`

Comment: Ahh..mind translating your variable names to english ?

Answer (score 0):

> Of course I can't use a default return

Why not?

Anyway, you get the error for exactly the reason described in the error message: you wrote a function that expects a reference to a string, and you are attempting to pass it a pointer to 200 strings (arrays degrade to pointers when passed to a function).  They are completely different things.

You either:

A) Take a pointer in the function (`string *vector`)

B) Make your array a vector and pass in a reference to it (`std::vector<string>& vector`)

C) Just return a vector and be done with it.  Don't assume that a copy will be created.  Copy elision and/or move semantics will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dadosPessoais[MAX_PESSOAS];
```

This is an array of strings of length MAX_PESSOAS. While this

```
void CadastroPessoas::lerDadosTodasPessoas(string &vetor)
{
   vetor = this->dadosPessoais;
}
```

function takes a single `string` object by reference. Change the function to accept an array; however, in this approach you've to copy each object one by one. Also it's generally discouraged to play around with array as they're notorious for being a hot bed of bugs.

A better approach is to use `std::array` (if you know the size is fixed) or `std::vector` (if you think the size can vary at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`string &vetor` is a reference to **one** string, I think you need `vector<string> &vetor` instead, `string dadosPessoais[MAX_PESSOAS]` is c-array array of strings, you can create vector of strings from it using vector constructor: `vector<string> tmp(dadosPessoais,dadosPessoais+MAX_PESSOAS)`. But it'd be better to push all strings right in vetor: `vetor.push("foo"); vetor.push("bar");`.